# VueJs - ncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. at VueComponent.onFocusin

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have imported a dialog component in my Document.vue. After that, i tried to take Add dialog.Then this console error occurs. When i remove my , this issue will be resolved. Please help me out.

Added code:

```
<template>
    <div class="components" :key="documentComponentkey">
        <!--Document Version History Component-->
        <DocumentHistoryComponents></DocumentHistoryComponents>
        <DialogViewComponents >
           <span class="slotcontent" v-if="progressCircular" slot="slotposition" slot-scope="slotProps">
                <ProgressCircularComponents  :value="uploadPercentage" :size="100" :width="10" :rotate= "360" ></ProgressCircularComponents>                
            </span>
        </DialogViewComponents>
       <HeaderComponents></HeaderComponents>
        <div class="components-sub-container">                          
            <!--Generic Form Component-->
            <BodyComponents>
            </BodyComponents>
        </div>       
        <!--Generic Footer Component-->
        <FooterComponents></FooterComponents>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import DocumentHistoryComponents from "./DocumentHistory";
    import  DialogViewComponents from "./../Dialog/Dialog";
    import  ProgressCircularComponents from "./../ProgressCircular/ProgressCircular";
    import HeaderComponents from "./../Card/Header/Header";
    import BodyComponents from "./../Card/Body/Body";
    import FooterComponents from "./../Card/Footer/Footer";
    /**
     * Component's properties and events
     */
    export default {
        components: {
            HeaderComponents,
            BodyComponents,
            FooterComponents,
            DocumentHistoryComponents,
            ProgressCircularComponents,
            DialogViewComponents
        },
```

[image: Console Error]

Anyone knows why this happens

Answer (score 0):

It's likely loop found within one of your components/routing, which triggers the error.

Comment: Hi I found that Dialog.vue component is called in both Header component and seperate component inside the Document.vue. Actually i need to call slot inside Dialog component.So how can i call slot inside Header component